# AWS C++ SDK Produces "closing connection 0" message on ShutdownAPI()

Tags: c++, aws-sdk

Example code:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <aws/core/Aws.h>
#include <aws/s3/S3Client.h>
#include <aws/s3/model/ListObjectsRequest.h>
#include <aws/s3/model/ListObjectsResult.h>

using std::cout;
using std::cerr;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

using Aws::S3::S3Client;

using Aws::S3::Model::Object;

using Aws::S3::Model::ListObjectsOutcome;
using Aws::S3::Model::ListObjectsRequest;
using Aws::S3::Model::ListObjectsResult;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Aws::SDKOptions options;
    Aws::InitAPI(options);

    ListObjectsRequest request;
    request.SetBucket("MyBucket");    
    ListObjectsOutcome outcome = client.ListObjects(request);
    Aws::ShutdownAPI(options);
}
```

When the S3Client drops out of scope, I get this output:

```
* Closing connection 0
```

I think this is coming out of libcurl, but because I don't have a direct handle to curl, I don't have a direct way of managing it using the libcurl way.

Am I don't something wrong? Is there a way to suppress this message?